# Get Text from DataGridViewComboxBoxCell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell in the following way

When adding items to the ComboBox:

```
    public void LoadLayouts()
    {
        ImmutableSet<string> layoutNames = _store.Current.Keys;
        var dgvComboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)this.schedulesDataGrid.Columns[1];

        foreach (string name in layoutNames)
        {
            dgvComboBox.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }
```

When trying to read back the value:

```
var combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) this.schedulesDataGrid[args.ColumnIndex, args.RowIndex];
string LayoutChosen = (string)combo.Value;
```

However, even if I can see that there is a value selected in the ComboBox, the Value comes back as null, and the `FormattedValue` comes back as "".

I've tried just setting the array of names as my DataSource, but then I'm not sure what to set for my Display and Value Members, considering I only have a single value (the name of the layout)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you attempt to read the cell's value, the row has not committed changes. If you have row headers visible, you will see the pencil icon on the row that has not been committed. This normally happens after the cell looses focus. You can force the issue by hooking into the in-place editing control combo-box and causing it to post EndEdit when it changes values:

```
void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox != null)
    {
        // remove any handler we may have added previously
        comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted);
        // add handler
        comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted);
    }
}

void comboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Allow current dispatch to complete (combo-box submitting its value)
    //  then EndEdit to commit the change to the row
    dgv.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dgv.EndEdit()));
}
```